bug with recent package upgrades
2024-09-06 17:20:58 upgrade libssl-dev:amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18
2024-09-06 17:20:58 upgrade libssl3:amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18
2024-09-06 17:20:58 upgrade libapparmor1:amd64 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2
2024-09-06 17:20:58 upgrade openssl:amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18
2024-09-06 17:20:59 upgrade vim:amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.18
2024-09-06 17:20:59 upgrade vim-tiny:amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.18
2024-09-06 17:20:59 upgrade vim-runtime:all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.18
2024-09-06 17:21:00 upgrade xxd:amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.18
2024-09-06 17:21:00 upgrade vim-common:all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.18
2024-09-06 17:21:00 upgrade apparmor:amd64 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2
2024-09-06 17:21:01 upgrade python3-twisted:all 22.1.0-2ubuntu2.4 22.1.0-2ubuntu2.5

i yesterday upgraded these packages and my server is using 100% cpu now without any traffic
32531 redis     20   0  140460  65008   8696 S  46.8   0.4   8:54.93 redis-server
 25659 shopb49+  21   1  414948 195280 125820 R  32.6   1.2   7:55.04 lsphp
 24555 shopb49+  21   1  401184 176124 122816 R  30.2   1.1   8:34.57 lsphp
 30698 shopb49+  21   1  408776 182388 119424 R  28.6   1.1   5:18.46 lsphp
 18663 shopb49+  21   1  411640 192968 127228 R  27.6   1.2  11:14.92 lsphp
 23737 shopb49+  21   1  417664 197704 127068 R  27.6   1.2   8:56.45 lsphp
 19532 shopb49+  21   1  415716 198360 128512 R  27.2   1.2  10:50.53 lsphp
 24556 shopb49+  21   1  449888 213852 152848 R  26.6   1.3   8:31.01 lsphp
 31484 shopb49+  21   1  400652 173028 119644 R  25.9   1.1   4:58.22 lsphp
 25089 shopb49+  21   1  408716 198420 135916 R  22.3   1.2   8:10.47 lsphp
 23738 shopb49+  21   1  399028 170524 119356 R  20.6   1.0   8:52.06 lsphp
 23178 shopb49+  21   1  411492 191612 125820 R  20.3   1.2   9:11.00 lsphp
 24273 shopb49+  21   1  415488 195160 125436 R  20.3   1.2   8:33.55 lsphp
 32952 shopb49+  21   1  413428 193220 125724 R  20.3   1.2   3:17.90 lsphp
  7384 mysql     20   0 4953972 583424  24040 S  12.3   3.6  32:42.51 mariadbd

please help me

Your paste is very unclear, and without any OS & especially release details which is critical for deb package problems. A random pick of a package version in your paste doesn't match any supported release of Ubuntu that is fully upgraded; eg. libssl-dev | 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18         | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x if you're using jammy or 22.04 being closest to what I saw in your paste, but your paste doesn't match what is expected for 22.04 either.

If you refer https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18/changelog you'll see the package you say you upgraded yesterday relates to an updated dated 30-July-2024, and should have been replaced by upgrades from 20-August-2024 ... so your yesterday makes little sense if you're using 22.04 as I suspect... OR that is the critical clue to check your actual system, sources etc. for problems; as your description (what little there was) doesn't match your paste!

can you let me know which log should i provide you?

Firstly you should edit your post and provide clear specifics... starting with what you're running, as you don't mention any Ubuntu product & release; and your details imply either an outdated Ubuntu system (that isn't well maintained) OR possibly a Ubuntu based system (where security fixes Ubuntu provides aren't applied).  You say "yesterday" yet packages in your paste match July... We're in September (your package as per my prior comment doesn't even match August updates if you were using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for example)

yes i am using ubuntu 22.04 with cyber panel

Please edit your question & add additional details there... this is a Q&A site (not a forum) & answers will be to your question; comments being intended from readers commenting on the question & get removed once addressed in the question.  I'd firstly check your sources as your details imply a system that hasn't been upgraded in some time as per my comments; your paste showing packages from July (not recent!) so check you're sources are correct without any missing lines.. then run sudo apt update & ensure you warnings/errors or missing lines etc...

You could also apt policy libssl-dev as that is the package I explored & your details would have been correct for late-July or early-August, not yesterday as you claim.. so explore why your sources, internet connection etc could cause such an out of date paste as your question contains...  That out of date detail is what I'd suggest looking to explain & expect once fixed your system will be all good.
